# Using gb4e inside of enumerate environment

Tags: lists, indentation, enumerate, linguistics, gb4e

I want to use the enumerate environment instead of the standard labeling that gb4e uses. I have the following code so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e, enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{exe}
\ex
\gll Saja mem-bawa surat itu kepada Ali.\\
      I \textsc{CAUSE}-bring letter the to Ali.\\
\glt I brought the letter to Ali.
\end{exe}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

If I omit the \ex line, the enumerate environment moves to the right too far, and if I include it, the indentation is good, but there are two labels, which is not correct. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only thing you need to do is remove the parentheses from the `gb4e` example (but the spacing is otherwise ok) then the  solution is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@exe}{(}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@exe}{)}{.}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex\gll Saja mem-bawa surat itu kepada Ali.\\
      I \textsc{CAUSE}-bring letter the to Ali\\
\glt I brought the letter to Ali.
\end{exe}
\begin{exe}\ex
\begin{xlist}
\ex[]{\gll Saja mem-bawa surat itu kepada Ali.\\
      I \textsc{CAUSE}-bring letter the to Ali\\
\glt I brought the letter to Ali.}
\ex[*]{\gll Ali Saja mem-bawa surat itu kepada. \\
      Ali I \textsc{CAUSE}-bring letter the to\\
\glt I brought the letter to Ali.}
\end{xlist}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of gb4e code]

If you need to change the indentation of the examples, you can use the glossing macros independent of the example numbering macros, and use `enumitem` for all the numbering, although with some modifications. I've set the appropriate indents for the two levels of numbering (you can change as needed), and made level 1 `resume` so that subsequent enumerations will start from the previous last number (as linguistic examples are usually numbered.) To remind you of the change, I've not actually loaded the `gb4e` package at all, just `cgloss4e` (although you could also load `gb4e`).

I've created a `\jg` macro for the grammaticality judgement, so that it aligns correctly.

(Not relevant to the question, but your gloss line (the second one) shouldn't contain any punctuation.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cgloss4e, enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{labelsep=1.25em,resume}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\alph*.,labelsep=1.25em}
\newcommand*{\jg}[1]{\llap{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\gll Saja mem-bawa surat itu kepada Ali.\\
      I \textsc{CAUSE}-bring letter the to Ali\\
\glt I brought the letter to Ali.
\item
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\gll Saja mem-bawa surat itu kepada Ali.\\
      I \textsc{CAUSE}-bring letter the to Ali\\
\glt I brought the letter to Ali.
\item
\gll \jg{*}Ali Saja mem-bawa surat itu kepada. \\
      Ali I \textsc{CAUSE}-bring letter the to\\
\glt I brought the letter to Ali.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of cgloss code]